# Enable more verbose DBLib errors

Tags: php, sql-server

When I var_dump($db->errorInfo()); when connecting from PHP via DBLib to a remote MSSQL database and any error occurs in a query, I get:

```
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 6522
    [2] => General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [6522] (severity 16) [(null)]
    [3] => -1
    [4] => 16
)
```

Error is not verbose.
Same script executing via SQLSRV on my local Windows machine gives more detailed explanation of the issue.

So, How to enable more verbose error in DBLib?